# Inverse Galois problem for function fields

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Books on Inverse Galois problem usually deal directly with the number field case. I am looking for a good reference for a proof of the following fact:

> **Every finite group is realizable for any function field** in one
>   variable over a algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.

It is ok if the reference is a research paper, but I would prefer a survey/textbook if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This paper gives a proof of the Inverse Galois Problem over $\mathbb{C}(z)$ and mentions the classical proof which uses the Riemann Existence Theorem. Whether you can replace $\mathbb{C}$ with $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ though, I'm not sure.

http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~fehm/papers/Cz.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look!

Answer (score 0):

*Groups as Galois groups* by Helmut volklein is a nice reference for your question. Moreover, it is not too difficult to follow the proof.